# How to arrange divs by css floats?

Tags: css-float

I have six divs and want to arange them in two rows and three columns

```
#topLeft {float:left;} //ok
#topMiddle {float:left;} //ok
#topRight {float:right;} //ok
#bottomLeft {}
#bottomMiddle {}
#bottomRight {}
```

In the second row I tried many combinations with floats and clears - without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `clear: left; float: left;` to `#bottomLeft` and `float: left;` to the last two.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5nGUe/2/

Comment: @ piers divs 3 and 6 should be right-aligned on the page, so div3 has float:right in my scenario.

Comment: @ piers i relly don't know what is the problem. But my divs don't work in the same manner. Anyway, I will continue to explore. ThanYoy for your efforts.